# Convert python list to JSON by appending a specific key value

Tags: python, json, list

I have a python list like this,

`vehicle = ['car', 'bus']`

And I want to convert this to JSON formated like below,

`[ { "vehicle": "car" }, { "vehicle": "bus" } ]`

I tried to convert to a dictionary too. But couldn't able to do it.

Comment: `[{"vehicle": v} for v in ['car', 'bus']]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go;

```
import json

vehicle = ['car', 'bus']

res = json.dumps([{'vehicle': v} for v in vehicle])

print(res)
```

**output**

```
[{"vehicle": "car"}, {"vehicle": "bus"}]
```

**Suggestion:**

I will recommend this instead;

```
import json

vehicle = ['car', 'bus']

res = json.dumps([{'vehicle': vehicle}])

print(res)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{"vehicle": ["car", "bus"]}]
```

Comment: I will try with your suggestion, it seems to be a better solution, Thanks!